# How do I remove qtsixa?

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

I have qtsixa installed but it is no longer of use to me. I didn't use apt-get so I can't remove it using that. any way to remove it?

Comment: Please do a simple search about your question before asking. In most of the cases, you will find the answer in a much faster time.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you say you didn't use apt-get or apt please try this method incase you did.

First, open a terminal by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

PPA purge, not only removes the PPA but **also uninstalls all the programs installed by the PPA**.

Install ppa-purge by using the following command:

`$ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

Now use it in following manner to purge the PPA:

`$ sudo ppa-purge PPA-URL-HERE`

The URL of the PPA for qtsixa can be found in the Software Sources list.

The ppa url should be, 'ppa:falk-t-j/qtsixa' according to, 'https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sixaxis'

### -

If that did not work, then you might have compiled it. You can remove the program binary by using which to find it.

Example(For the bash program. You **shouldn't** remove bash.)

`$ which bash
/usr/bin/bash`

Now that you know where the bash binary is located you can remove it with rm.
Example:

`$ sudo rm /usr/bin/bash`

You should be able to follow the same steps to find the qtsixa binary.